# calling Type.MakeGenericType() with null arguments

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic type:

```
MyType<T1, T2, T3>
```

and i want to do this:

```
typeof(MyType<,,>).MakeGenericType(new [] { null, null, string});
```

so i end up with:

```
MyType<,,string>
```

But, you can't pass null types into MakeGenericType (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx).

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you adding in the other types later on?

Comment: i need to support open generic types, i have rules to apply to MyTypes based on their generic arguments. so a MyType<x,y,z> would get the Mytype<,,z> rule applied to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I avoided it like this:

```
var args = typeof(MyType<,,>).GetGenericArguments();
args[2] = typeof(string);
typeof(MyType<,,>).MakeGenericType(args);
```